# Problem with Performance Counters on XP 64 Bit

Tags: c#, windows-xp, performancecounter

I've got a C# application that monitors memory/processor performance. I only need to perform read operations -- so the app *should* run fine as a limted user.

The application runs fine on every OS/user level (admin/limited) combo I can throw at it (XP/Vista/7) except when I hit XP 64 bit. With XP x64 it crashes with an access exception saying I don't have sufficient permissions.

Has anyone succeeded in getting performance counters to work under limited users on XP x64? If so - how'd you get it to work?

A couple of notes:

- I can't modify the registry
- I can't accept the restriction that users must be in the "Performance Monitors" user group

Like I said, the app runs fine on XP (x86), Vista (x86/64), 7 (x86/64) -- so I'm not sure why XP x64 is being so picky....

All help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Dan

Edit:

Here's the line that fails:

```
c = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total", true);
```

Comment: XP x64 was training wheels for a 64-bit operating system.  Lots of warts, bits and pieces that weren't yet converted, abandoned completely when SP3 shipped.  You really shouldn't bother, upgrade tomorrow and never look back.